# returning binary image in json result shows serialization error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am returning json result from controller action and result includes the binary image and i want to show it in view using javascript. but it shows the `Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.`

Action which called using ajax on page load

```
public ActionResult LoadBooks()
    {          
            var v = from t in db.BookTbls
                    where t.IsDisplay==true
                    select new BookVM
                    {
                        BookID=t.BookID,
                        BookName=t.BookName,
                        BookPrize=t.BookPrize,
                        BookImagepath=t.BookImagepath,
                        BinaryImage=t.BinaryImage
                    };

            List<BookVM> list = new List<BookVM>();
            foreach(var temp in v.ToList())
            {
                BookVM obj = new BookVM();
                obj.BookID = temp.BookID;
                obj.BookName = temp.BookName;
                obj.BookPrize = temp.BookPrize;
                obj.BookImagepath = temp.BookImagepath;
                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(temp.BinaryImage);
                var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
                obj.BImage = imgsrc;//BImage is string variable from model
                list.Add(obj);
            }          
            return Json(v.OrderBy(p => p.BookName).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

in short i just want that result in view, its not even goes in success(result)
just showing console error mentioned above.

Comment: Probably there is a `maxJsonLength` property that you can set to a higher limit, as this seem to be the problem highlighted by the error message.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow,

The MaxJsonLength property cannot be unlimited, is an integer property that defaults to 102400 (100k).

You can set the MaxJsonLength property on your web.config: the max you can have i believe is 2147483644.

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

As a workaround, you can do the following within your Controller (or anywhere really):

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

// For simplicity just use Int32's max value.
// You could always read the value from the config section mentioned above.
serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;

var resultData = new { Value = "foo", Text = "var" };
var result = new ContentResult{
    Content = serializer.Serialize(resultData),
    ContentType = "application/json"
};
return result;
```

[Mirosoft Documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.scriptingjsonserializationsection.maxjsonlength?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Configuration_ScriptingJsonSerializationSection_MaxJsonLength)

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your response, but actually i want to send that result back through a list as I created above in my code. And here if i use JavaScriptSerializer(). i dont know how to store that contentResult in a viewmodel and how to store it in list. I am so sorry i am new to the dotnet. please help me.